# Database schema design for dynamic CRM with inter-account interaction

Tags: database-design

In a traditional CRM, we have some basic objects such as users, organisations and contacts. The users belong to an organisation's CRM account.

A very basic schema might look like this:

```
User
----
id
account_id
username/email
password
role
[account permissions type field]
```

Users belong to accounts:

```
Account
-------
id
name
[license type field]
```

Users add affiliated organisations (customers, suppliers, subcontractors):

```
Organisation
------------
id
name
address
account_id
```

Users also add contacts within these affiliated organisations:

```
Contact
-------
id
organisation_id
name
email
phone_number
role
[account_id?]
```

Suppose you had a customer who also had an account within the same CRM, you have already added this organisation and some contacts to the database. What would be the best practice for the following:

- ability to add static organisations and contacts same as traditional CRM
- where organisation entries match an existing account with the CRM and the 2 organisations wish to share some B2B type data /communications direct through the CRM, allow them to connect
- where an account is connected to another account, the static 'organisation' entry in the database is replaced with a live connection to  the other organisations account.
- when the account owner gives permission, "contact" entries are updated with the equivalent users live information for connected accounts.

The User-Account relationship is synonymous with the Contact-Organisation relationship, presumably we would need to build a relationship between Account-Organisation and User-Contact. My question is what would be the ideal design/what are the design considerations for implementing this hybrid static CRM/social environment?